# Maximum memory size for an XCOM in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I was wondering if there is any memory size limit for an `XCOM` in [airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) ?

Answer (score 8):

Airflow is NOT a processing framework. It is not Spark, neither Flink. **Airflow is an orchestrator**, and it the best orchestrator. There is no optimisations to process big data in Airflow neither a way to distribute it (maybe with one executor, but this is another topic). If you try to exchange big data between your tasks, you will end up with a memory overflow error! Oh, and do you know the xcom limit size in Airflow?

It depends on the database you use:

1. SQLite: 2 GB
2. Postgres: 1 GB
3. MySQL: 64 KB

Yes, 64 Kilobytes for MySQL! Again, use XComs only for sharing small amount of data.

ref: https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-xcom/

Comment: Could you explain what is 1 Go? Thanks!

Comment: @Pedro Muñoz It's a typo, it should be "SQLite: 2 GB" and "Postgres: 1 Go".

Comment: @josh-fell "SQLite: 2 GB" and "Postgres: 1 GB" right? :D

Answer (score 7):

According to the source code [check this source code link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/models/xcom.html), maximum XCOM size is 48KB.

Answer (score 6):

After looking at the source code it looks there is none, the type is a large binary in SQLAlchemy. [Code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e1c0433127d0a19235b12a966af2dbd8016c53c8/airflow/models/xcom.py#L43)
So according to the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.LargeBinary) is an  unlengthed binary type for the target platform, such as BLOB on MySQL and BYTEA for PostgreSQL.

Comment: so there is no hard limit for storing as an XCOM variable?