# How to dispatch numerous xcoms from a task to another task?

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

I am brand new to Airflow and I am trying to understand data dispatch between tasks. The [documentation for xcom](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html) (and a [good article](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-passing-data-between-tasks?tab=taskflow#example-dag-using-xcoms)) helped me to understand the basics of a 1:1 data flow.

Consider now `task_one` that fetches an API that provides a JSON: a large list of small dicts (after deserializing). I would like to have `task_two` that somehow gets one of these dicts and processes it further. For performance/scaling reasons, I expect that 10 concurrent `task_two` would be perfect.

How should I engineer my DAG? Specifically, is there a way to

- tell `task_two` *"take the next xcom provided by `task_one` until there are none left"*?
- limit the number of concurrent `task_two`?

A generalization of this question would be:

- should the logic in `task_two` account for the retrieval of xcom data in a loop until the data is depleted ...
- ... OR is there a built-in, recommended way to setup the DAG so that `task_two` just retrieves one piece of data and is restarted by the DAG until the data provided by `task_one` is depleted? (in which case the DAG manages the startup of 10 `task-two` and the provision of data to each of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like [Dynamic Tasks Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic) is really the answer for you.

Here is an example of how it works:

```
@task
def api_call():
    return [{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}, {"c": 3}]


@task(
    max_active_tis_per_dag=2 # if you want to control the number of concurrent tasks
)
def handle_output(arg):
    print(arg)


with DAG(dag_id="dynamic-map", start_date=datetime(2022, 4, 2)) as dag:
    handle_output.expand(arg=api_call())
```

Airflow will split the array from the `api_call` and will create 3 tasks with appropriate inputs.

[image: DAG's Graph View]

You can make sure, by looking at output:

```
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2023-09-17T22:13:18.891076+00:00
[2023-09-17, 22:13:21 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} INFO - {'a': 1}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid this method because the docs repeatedly warn against passing large amounts of data between tasks. This is the reason I wanted to dispatch small chunks (an element of the list) to one or many tasks (ideally many, limited to 10). But again, I am just starting so any feedback on my misunderstanding is very much welcome!

Comment: First of all, what do you consider a large amount of data? You can check limitations here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66452528/6097123

Comment: Mapped tasks are really the way to go here. When you map the task out Airflow will split the array up and send a single element to each task, and if you want to limit how many are running at a given time look into task pools. As far as the size limitations, there are ways to handle that. Look into custom xcom backend that store in blob storage

Comment: @TevettGoad: thank you, this clarifies the answer (now accepted) - I did not realize that the array would be split and sent element by element.